# Teschl Functionalanalysis, Problem 2.5 with orthogonal polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis

I am struggling with the following problem which is from "Topics in Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis" written by Gerald Teschl (problem 2.5, page 56f):

Let $I = (a,b)$ be some interval and consider the scalar product $\langle f,g \rangle := \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{*}g(x)w(x)dx$ associated with some positive weight function $w(x)$. Let $P_j(x) = x^{j}+...$ be the corresponding monic orthogonal polynomials obtained by applying
the Gram–Schmidt procedure (without normalization) to the monomials:
$$\int_{a}^{b} P_i(x)P_j(x)w(x)dx = \begin{cases}
\alpha_{j}^{2}, & i = j \\
0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Let $\overline{P}_j (x):= \alpha_{j}^{-1}P_j(x)$ be the corresponding orthonormal polynomials
and show that they satisfy the three term recurrence relation:
$$a_j\overline{P}_{j+1}(x) + b_j\overline{P}_j(x) + a_{j−1}\overline{P}_{j−1}(x) = x\overline{P}_j(x),$$
or equivalently
$$P_{j+1}(x) = (x−b_{j})P_{j}(x)−a_{j-1}^{2}P_{j−1}(x),$$
where
$$a_j := \int_{a}^{b}x\overline{P}_{j+1}(x)\overline{P}_j(x)w(x)dx, \ \ \ b_{j} := \int_{a}^{b}x\overline{P}_{j}(x)^{2}w(x)dx.$$
Here we set $P_{−1}(x) = \overline{P}_{−1}(x) ≡ 0$ for notational convenience.

I would seriously appreciate any help I could get because I am right now pretty overwhelmed by the sheer complexity of this task. I don't even know where to start here.